# Can I remove timeout for just one call? Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I created a **`axios`** client

```
const backendClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: window['getConfig']?.url?.backend,
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),
  timeout: window['getConfig']?.timeout || 30000,
});
```

and I make the every calls with that client in my application. but I want to remove timeout for just one specific call. Is there a way to do it ? U can see my fetch below.

```
 const loadMessageDetail = () => {
        backendClient.get(getDashboardDataQuery())
            .then((response) => {
               ......
            }).catch(() => {
            ......
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done simply by overriding the global `timeout` setting in the configuration of that specific request. Something like:

```js
const loadMessageDetail = () => {
    backendClient.get(getDashboardDataQuery(), { timeout: 0 }) // <----Notice this config object
        .then((response) => {
           //...
        }).catch(() => {
        //...
    });
}
```